# Creating anonymous functions inside conditional statements

Tags: javascript, dom

I've a snippet like this :

```
if(el) {
    el.addEventListener("click", function(){
        if (body.classList.contains("el-is-open")) {
            body.classList.remove("el-is-open");
        } else {
            body.classList.add("el-is-open");
        }
    });

    foo.addEventListener("click", function(){
        body.classList.remove("el-is-open");
    });
}
```

Is okay to wrap these statements inside a condition? I'm new to js so I'm not sure if is okay to do..

Before I always got:

```
uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

After this I can have all my js inside the same file, and only run it if the document have the id el (i.e). Thanks

Comment: For `el` that's fine (if it doesn't exist - what would u add event listener to? By why is `foo.addEventListener` inside the condition as well?

Comment: Just check why the el does not exist. Maybe you are trying to manipulate the DOM, before it is loaded :)

Comment: @YuriyGalanter let's say that foo is an id of a close button inside a modal or so, it only appears when el appears because is a child of el..

Comment: @gustavodidomenico the code runs after the dom is loaded.

Comment: It's completely acceptable to use if conditions (`null` is *falsey*). If `el` is `null`, then that means you don't actually have a reference to an element which may be expected behavior or could be an indication of an error in the code.

Comment: @cpburnz so doing that is okay and not a bad habit for the future?

Comment: @TiS It's not a bad habit so long as it is expected that `el` could be `null` in which case you need the conditional if statement. If you expect `el` to always exist, then `el == null` would indicate an error in which case you would not want the conditional if statement and instead track down the error.